# Get current User outside of Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

On an ASP.NET Core 2.2 controller I have the following:

```
var principal = this.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

var authenticated = this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

var claims = this.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims;

var id = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

I am able to check if the user is `authenticated` and gets the `claims` including `id`.

How can I do the same outside of the `Controller` where I do not have `this.User`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Inject `IHttpContextAccessor` interface into the target class. This will give access to the current `User` via the `HttpContext`

This provides an opportunity to abstract this feature by creating a service to provide just the information you want (Which is the current logged in user)

```
public interface IUserService {
    ClaimsPrincipal GetUser();
}

public class UserService : IUserService {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal GetUser() {
        return accessor?.HttpContext?.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
    }
}
```

You need to setup `IHttpContextAccessor` now in `Startup.ConfigureServices` in order to be able to inject it:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
```

and inject your service where needed.

> It's important to note that `HttpContext` could be *null*. Just because
>   you have `IHttpContextAccessor`, doesn't mean that you're going to
>   actually be able to always get the `HttpContext`. Importantly, the code where
>   you're using this *must* be within the request pipeline in some way or
>   `HttpContext` will be *null*.

*Credit [@ChrisPratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt)* via comment

Comment: It's important to note that `HttpContext` could be null. Just because you have `IHttpContextAccessor`, doesn't mean that you're going to actually be able to get the `HttpContext`. Importantly, the code where you're using this *must* be within the request pipeline in some way or `HttpContext` will be null.

Comment: Why is `services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();` needed? `IHttpContextAccessor` needs it but `AddHttpContextAccessor()` doesn't add it?

Comment: `UserService` is a custom service and therefore needs to be registered separately. `IHttpContextAccessor` doesn't need it, it's opposite, its instance is injected into the `UserService`

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` interface into a non-web service, because that gives it a dependency on ASP.NET Core, making it unusable outside the context of a web request.

Instead, resolve the user from within the controller or page you're in:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity!.Name);

// or by Id
var userId = User.FindFirst(Claims.UserId).Value;
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
```

Now you have an `ApplicationUser` instance (or whatever you named your Identity user entity), which you can pass to the appropriate service:

```
await otherService.DoSomething(foo, bar, user);
```

Comment: Could you instead inject the current user's ClaimsPrincipal object itself into the UserManager service?  It would of course be up to you to get/create/inject it properly depending on the type of application.  Curious as to your thoughts.  Thanks-

Comment: IMHO: no. You want to pass to your business logic which business user is doing something. By passing a principal, you send too much and at the same time too little data.