# how to get logged in user out of controller action method in .Net WebAPI

Tags: claims-based-identity, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm able to get a logged-in user by using "User" in my controller action. I want to get this User to another method that is outside of the controller class.I tried using the below question, but I'm unable to succeed.[Get current User outside of Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990635/get-current-user-outside-of-controller)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just pass the User object (ClaimsPrincipal type) as a parameter to the next method in some other class? or to the constructor of the other class?